# C# Tree of objects filtering based on elements type

Tags: c#, list, filter, tree

I know similar questions have been asked before but mine has some key differences that change it.
So lets say I have a class with the following in C#

```
public class Node
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public Node Parent { get; set; }

        public List<Node> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

And I have some sort of tree structure with types similar to this:

```
N1
  - N1
  - N1
N2
  - N3
  - N1
N3
N4
  - N5
      - N1
         -N6
N1
N1
  - N2
```

How do I filter by Type: `N1` so the above tree looks like this:

```
N1
  - N1
  - N1
N2
  - N1
N4
  - N5
      - N1
N1
N1
```

Basically I want to filter by Type: `N1` but leave the parent nodes if some child node has Type: `N1`.
Im looking for simple C# method(s) that can achieve this, I do not want to add any library or anything.
Something like:
`tree = FilterTree(type, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion using recursion and a [`Func<Node, bool>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-6.0) delegate.

If you have a `List<Node> tree`, you could implement extension methods that are calling each other:

```csharp
public static IEnumerable<Node> BuildTreeWithLeafNodes(
    this IEnumerable<Node> topNodes, 
    Func<Node, bool> leafNodeCondition)
{
    return topNodes
        .Select(topNode => topNode.GetSubTreeWithLeafNodes(leafNodeCondition))
        .Where(subTree => subTree != null);
}

public static Node GetSubTreeWithLeafNodes(
    this Node node, 
    Func<Node, bool> leafNodeCondition)
{
    if (node.Children != null && node.Children.Any())
    {
        node.Children = node.Children
            .BuildTreeWithLeafNodes(leafNodeCondition)
            .ToList();
    
        if (node.Children != null && node.Children.Any())
        {
            return node;
        }
    }
    
    return leafNodeCondition(node) ? node : null;
}
```

and get the filtered tree by calling:

```
var filteredTree = tree.BuildTreeWithLeafNodes(node => node.Type == "N1");
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ThrO6).

---

**What's happening?**

`BuildTreeWithLeafNodes()` takes a collection of `Node`s and returns a collection of `Node`s where the following selection conditions apply for each **node** in the original collection:

- if the **node** is originally childless or none of the descendants satisfies the `leafNodeCondition`, the **node** (without children) is included in the return collection *only if* the **node** itself satisfies the `leafNodeCondition`.
- if the **node** originally has children and at least one of the descendants satisfies `leafNodeCondition`, the **node**'s sub tree (`node.Children` with their descendants) is adjusted so that it only contains branches where the leaf node of each branch satisfies `leafNodeCondition`, and the **node with the adjusted sub tree** is included in the return collection.

The whole process can be visualized as a "descendant trimming" that is working itself up from each original leaf node and towards the top nodes (the original collection).

Basically, the way `BuildTreeWithLeafNodes()` and `GetSubTreeWithLeafNodes()` are calling each other, each original `Node`'s sub trees (`Children` and their descendants) are being traversed all the way down to each respective sub tree's leaf node. If the leaf node does not satisfy the `leafNodeCondition`, it is removed from the parent node's `Children`. Once a parent node loses all its children (i.e. if none of the children satisfy the `leafNodeCondition`), the parent node itself will be removed from its own parent's `Children` unless it satisfies the `leafNodeCondition`.

Comment: you're a legend, ill will test this tomorrow and see if it works. Either way thats for responding

Comment: You're welcome, I'm curious to hear if it fits your needs or not. I haven't tried it for larger trees than the example you provided, by the way.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that!